# Pre-loading custom UITableViewCells then having them be re-used in the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've seen solutions where there is a need to create all required heavyweight UITableViewCells prior to loading the tableview, which works when you have a relatively small number of rows. In that case, tableviewcells can be created before calling reloadData, stored in an array then used as required in the cellForRowAt method instead of using dequeueReusableCell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustCell") as! CustomCell
```

However, for my app I can't create all required tableview cells since it could be 500 or more very heavy cells which would balloon the app's memory use.

The tableviewcells contain a WKWebview which loads a web page containing a large amount of Javascript code; loading isn't fast and and the tableviews will generate the cells so quickly that they will effectively attempt to web load at the same time, so that there's a heavy CPU price that can cause errors in loading. Ideally each of the tableview's cells needs to be prepared for use sequentially then added to the tableview.

I need to create the number of cells that this UITableView needs to be visible at any time (plus the few it uses in advance) and reuse them via dequeueReusableCell as the user scrolls.

Can I can pre-create the cells using a method as below then have those cells reused in the tableview? i.e. can I use dequeueReusableCell outside the context of the cellForRowAt method?

```
func setupCells () {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustCell") as! CustomCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cellArray.append(cell)
}
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Why do you need to pre-create any cells? Why not just use a table view as it is meant to be used? What issue are you attempting to solve?

Comment: Good point, I'll amend the original question

Comment: I've updated the question to explain the circumstances

Comment: You need to display the cells first with something to show progress while the webview is loading. Once your webview has loaded, add it to the cell.

Comment: Rakesha, yes that's another route - adding loaded webviews to the cells. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can initialize Cell outside `UITableView Method`

```
var arrVideoCell = [VideoTableViewCell]() //Intialize variable

//Intialization
    fileprivate func getNewFeildCell() -> VideoTableViewCell
    {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VideoTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! CellName
        let urlString = URL(string: "URL")
        cell.viwVideo.loadVideoURL(urlString!)
        return cell
    }

//For Set data in method

func configureAudioData()
{
    for _ in 0...4
    {
        let cell = getNewFeildCell()
        arrVideoCell.append(cell)
    }

    self.tblAudioVideo.reloadData()
}
```

//Tableview Delegate, DataSource

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
        let cell = arrVideoCell[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nihar, but I would need to create every cell used, I can't do that because there are too many of them needed - I need to be able to create a small number of them, load them and reuse them.